# ffmpeg -segment_time produces spoiled segments

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I use this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/) instead of installing ffmpeg directly to my OS X. What I want to achieve is to split some .avi file into pieces with duration of 30 seconds each. Here is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i /mounted/fixed.avi -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -segment_time 30 -f segment /mounted/cutted_video/output%03d.avi
```

The result is as expected, almost %) There is a number of files from output000.avi to outputxxx.avi. However, only the first one has both video and audio, rest files are muted and with spoiled second frame (mplayer freezes on this frame until I fastforward). If I remove audio map parameter:

```
ffmpeg -i /mounted/fixed.avi -c copy -map 0:0 -segment_time 30 -f segment /mounted/cutted_video/output%03d.avi
```

ffmpeg produces nice videos (even with accurate timing more or less), but it's obviously muted.
The question is what I'm doing wrong here? I suppose it relates somehow to audio mapping, but I didn't find any answer yet. I will highly appreciate any help since I'm fairly new to video processing.

P.S. Of course there is another solution - to write pretty simple python script to cut video into pieces with -ss param, but since there is built-in functionality in ffmpeg, I want to use it.

Comment: Paste the full console output of the first command. Also, try mapping only the audio and check if the audio is present in all segments.

Comment: please find the output here: https://gist.github.com/Nbooo/2416122b4efed0f5a8369a28595eb298

Comment: If I map only the audio it is present in all segments.

Comment: Add `-reset_timestamps 1`. And you may need to output to mp4. An additional option to add is `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero`

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you! `-reset_timestamps 1` works perfectly without any additional manipulations! This is the answer to my question. Thanks again!